# Grouping records?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table with records similar to this:

AJ - Oakville - 3
AJ - Oakville - 1
AJ - Toronto  - 1
AJ - Toronto  - 1
AJ - Toronto  - 1

I'd like my report to simply list the totals, so...

AJ - Oakville - 4
AJ - Toronto  - 3

I've been messing around with this all day to no avail, and I have a feeling it's something very simple I'm overlooking. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions:

- insert a group on the city field (this will add group-header and group-footer for the city)
- select the numeric field, then select Insert | Summary (this will add a summarized field in the group footer)
- copy or move the 'AJ' field to the group header
- copy or move the summarized field in the group footer to the header
- hide the details section

Comment: Thanks Craig - I basically did exactly this while waiting for a response! Figures. Would help if I had used CR before today. Kudos!